# Getting 36 volts on light circuit when switch is off

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I have a new addition on house and am having an electrical issue. On one light/ceiling fan circuit....I get 120v when switch is on....36 volts when switch is off. I’ve checked for bad/leaky switch. I’ve double checked wiring for reversed neutral/hot (powering neutral leg). I’ve checked for scuffed scratched wires or potential shorts. I’m at a loss.  What am I missing here.

Comment: Exactly how and where are you testing it?

Comment: And exactly how are you switching it on and off? Is it a toggle switch or a dimmer / electronic switching device? If you go open the circuit breaker feeding that circuit, do you still read the phantom voltage?

Comment: Testing the wires at the light box that will attach to light fixture. I have a 12-2 Romex hot wire and a 12-2 romex switch leg at the ceiling box. I’m connecting black hot to white switch leg that goes to bottom Pole of standard light switch. Black wire of switch leg on Top pole

Comment: Is the fan still hooked up to the romex when your taking the readings?

Comment: Sounds like perfectly routine phantom voltage, which is basically acting like a radio antenna, the way a crystal radio can hear AM stations without a battery.  Very sensitive voltmeters can pick it up, and your run-of-the-mill cheap DVM is very sensitive.  **Is a light wired to the wiring under test?**  Or have you disconnected the light to take the measurement?   The presence of the light in the circuit will tamp down that phantom voltage and force it to read correctly.

Comment: No fan or light is attached when I’m testing. but voltage is enough to shock. I have a sperry dm6800 using for test. It shows 120v when switch is on and 37v when switch is off. I’ve also pulled breaker and checked continuity from breaker to ground.. I get 1.67 ohms

Comment: Is this part of a multi wire branch circuit? Normally you get a hit from the neutral. Everything can be turned off on this circuit if not handle tied or common trip you can get bit because the other circuit is in use.

Comment: What *issue* is this 37V causing for you?

Comment: Think I resolved problem. I think drywall guys put a nail thru wire.  Isolated switch leg and tested with a new wire...worked fine.  Will pull new wire Monday

Comment: @Dcg314 -- post back once you've pulled the new *cable* (note, it needs to be a cable, not just an individual wire) and let us know if that fixes it!

Comment: Did not fix. Still getting 36 volts. Ran a new hot wire to ceiling fan boxdirwct from breaker...connected switch leg with same results. This is a breaker from a sub panel. Could the absence of a 4th wire ground from main service cause this?  It only happens at the metal ceiling fan boxes. None of the plastic receptacle boxes or any other circuit has this issue.